# Artifactory docker registry: Forbidden error

Tags: docker, nginx, artifactory, docker-engine, nginx-config

We are trying up to setup Artifactory in our corporate setup (there is a proxy server in the mix). Nginx, Artifactory and PostgreSQL are running in containers (spun up using JFrog's docker compose example).

But I am unable to successfully login to docker using cli command (`docker login`). I am getting the following error:

```
Error response from daemon: Get https://docker.artifactory/v2/: Forbidden
```

**This is my /etc/hosts file:**

```
xx.xx.x.xxx docker-local.artifactory docker-remote.artifactory bintray-docker-remote.artifactory docker-virtual.artifactory docker.artifactory artifactory
```

**This is the artifactory.conf file:**

```
###########################################################
## this configuration was generated by JFrog Artifactory ##
###########################################################

## server configuration
server {

    listen 80 ;
    server_name ~(?<repo>.+)\.artifactory artifactory;

    if ($http_x_forwarded_proto = '') {
        set $http_x_forwarded_proto  $scheme;
    }
    ## Application specific logs
    ## access_log /var/log/nginx/artifactory-access.log timing;
    ## error_log /var/log/nginx/artifactory-error.log;
    rewrite ^/$ /artifactory/webapp/ redirect;
    rewrite ^/artifactory/?(/webapp)?$ /artifactory/webapp/ redirect;
    rewrite ^/(v1|v2)/(.*) /artifactory/api/docker/$repo/$1/$2;
    chunked_transfer_encoding on;
    client_max_body_size 0;
    location /artifactory/ {
    proxy_read_timeout  900;
    proxy_pass_header   Server;
    proxy_cookie_path   ~*^/.* /;
    if ( $request_uri ~ ^/artifactory/(.*)$ ) {
        proxy_pass          http://xx.xx.x.xxx:8081/artifactory/$1;
    }
    proxy_pass          http://xx.xx.x.xxx:8081/artifactory/;
    proxy_set_header    X-Artifactory-Override-Base-Url $http_x_forwarded_proto://$host:$server_port/artifactory;
    proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Port  $server_port;
    proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Proto $http_x_forwarded_proto;
    proxy_set_header    Host              $http_host;
    proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For   $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }
}
```

**Other helpful information:**

**docker info**

```
[root@jprdevops1 source]# docker info
Containers: 42
 Running: 29
 Paused: 0
 Stopped: 13
Images: 28
Server Version: 17.06.2-ee-10
Storage Driver: devicemapper
 Pool Name: docker-253:0-201376616-pool
 Pool Blocksize: 65.54kB
 Base Device Size: 10.74GB
 Backing Filesystem: xfs
 Data file: /dev/loop0
 Metadata file: /dev/loop1
 Data Space Used: 4.668GB
 Data Space Total: 107.4GB
 Data Space Available: 54.84GB
 Metadata Space Used: 8.266MB
 Metadata Space Total: 2.147GB
 Metadata Space Available: 2.139GB
 Thin Pool Minimum Free Space: 10.74GB
 Udev Sync Supported: true
 Deferred Removal Enabled: true
 Deferred Deletion Enabled: true
 Deferred Deleted Device Count: 0
 Data loop file: /var/lib/docker/devicemapper/devicemapper/data
 Metadata loop file: /var/lib/docker/devicemapper/devicemapper/metadata
 Library Version: 1.02.146-RHEL7 (2018-01-22)
Logging Driver: json-file
Cgroup Driver: cgroupfs
Plugins: 
 Volume: local
 Network: bridge host macvlan null overlay
 Log: awslogs fluentd gcplogs gelf journald json-file logentries splunk syslog
Swarm: active
 NodeID: 73zg9m9we01buq3gvkf3zwh9t
 Is Manager: true
 ClusterID: ybotbith447qdwu5fjvkitb0a
 Managers: 1
 Nodes: 3
 Orchestration:
  Task History Retention Limit: 5
 Raft:
  Snapshot Interval: 10000
  Number of Old Snapshots to Retain: 0
  Heartbeat Tick: 1
  Election Tick: 10
 Dispatcher:
  Heartbeat Period: 5 seconds
 CA Configuration:
  Expiry Duration: 3 months
  Force Rotate: 0
  External CAs:
    cfssl: https://xx.xx.x.xxx:12381/api/v1/cfssl/sign
 Root Rotation In Progress: false
 Node Address: xx.xx.x.xxx
 Manager Addresses:
  xx.xx.x.xxx:2377
Runtimes: runc
Default Runtime: runc
Init Binary: docker-init
containerd version: 6e23458c129b551d5c9871e5174f6b1b7f6d1170
runc version: 462c82662200a17ee39e74692f536067a3576a50
init version: 949e6fa
Security Options:
 seccomp
  Profile: default
Kernel Version: 3.10.0-693.21.1.el7.x86_64
Operating System: Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server 7.4 (Maipo)
OSType: linux
Architecture: x86_64
CPUs: 4
Total Memory: 15.51GiB
Name: jprdevops1
ID: CQEY:6LPH:YT2U:EHNG:KDSZ:QH7L:2EOM:2HYH:JF4P:HPNB:4CF3:FCDU
Docker Root Dir: /var/lib/docker
Debug Mode (client): false
Debug Mode (server): false
Http Proxy: http://xx.xx.xx.xx:80/
Https Proxy: https://xx.xx.xx.xx:80/
Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/
Experimental: false
Insecure Registries:
 127.0.0.0/8
Live Restore Enabled: false

WARNING: devicemapper: usage of loopback devices is strongly discouraged for production use.
         Use `--storage-opt dm.thinpooldev` to specify a custom block storage device.
```

**docker version:**

```
Client: Docker Enterprise Edition (EE) 2.0
 Version:       17.06.2-ee-10
 API version:   1.30
 Go version:    go1.8.7
 Git commit:    66261a0
 Built: Fri Apr 27 00:38:41 2018
 OS/Arch:       linux/amd64

Server: Docker Enterprise Edition (EE) 2.0
 Engine:
  Version:      17.06.2-ee-10
  API version:  1.30 (minimum version 1.12)
  Go version:   go1.8.7
  Git commit:   66261a0
  Built:        Fri Apr 27 00:40:03 2018
  OS/Arch:      linux/amd64
  Experimental: false
```

**What I tried?**

```
•   Docker proxies are configured correctly in docker.service.d dir (as per documentation procedure)

•   Proxy information is also set in Artifactory (Admin -> Configuration -> Proxies)

•   Added Google's public dns server details in /etc/resolv.conf

•   Restarted the docker daemon

•   Added self signed cert to /etc/pki and updated ca certs.
```

I am really exhausted and have hit a dead end. Need guidance on successfully logging in to docker using CLI.

Regards

Aditya

Comment: The request to docker.artifactory is https. The config you showed us is only http. Is there another config to look at? Or perhaps, try configuring the insecure registries with "docker.artifactory".

Comment: @Rickkwa port 443 is used by another service. Can we use port 8443 instead?

Comment: I think @Rickkwa is on the right track. This seems like an Artifactory+Nginx config issue.

Comment: @Rickkwa I have added listen ssl 443 in the nginx.conf but still I am getting forbidden request. I know something is broken somewhere, but I don't know where is it.

Comment: @AdityaKrishnakant Can you update the question with the new nginx conf? Also, I'm not at all familiar with Artifactory so idk how much help I can be.